# Cross Browser Issue. Need advice

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, cross-browser

I designed an input upload box using jquery that i googled somewhere, problem is the "Browse" Button is not working(not clickable) on IE. Can anyone take a peek on the code and help me what i should do or tweak for this to work on IE? Thanks a lot. I've included the html/css/js files on jsfiddle bellow.

[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2zHX/)

Answer (score 1):

The "browse" button that you added doesn't work in IE 7/8/9, Chrome, or Firefox. You may have a different experience, which reinforces the point I'll try to make.

It's better to either use a Flash-based file upload to completely replace the default UI (I believe GMail still does this), or just leave the default input alone, ugly/inconsistent as it may be. There are many hacks to style file uploads, but no real solutions (at least that I've come across).

The closest thing I have found to a pure HTML/CSS solution was to overlay a styled button on top of the file input's "browse" button and hide the rest of it. I then mimicked async capabilities by placing the whole thing inside of an `IFRAME`. This solution did/does still work but I wasted hours tweaking it visually, added a bunch of extra code to hook the `IFRAME` to the containing page, and increased the complexity of the overall solution. And the next update to any browser may break it.

HTML 5 does offer much more flexibility around the file upload process ([see here](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/)) but such solutions aren't universally supported yet and still don't necessarily address aesthetic concerns.

[Drag and drop capabilities](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/) may be useful to you as you can hide the file input altogether. You may be able to use a solution like this in newer browsers and degrade to a standard file input on older browsers which do not support it.

[Another example](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/3/index.html) with progressive enhancement.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i could have spent hours and hours wasting time on it. Fortunately i found another solution at cssdeck.com. Works for all browser with a few minor defects on IE. Thanks again.