# What are the possible css attributes to set for a HTML file element?

Tags: css

I want a `file` element of my formulaire to have the same css as textfields having this css :

```
.formulaire .inputlong {  // formulaire is the form and inputlong is the name of the css for textfields
    width: 250px;
    background-color:#FFF; 
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#b80500;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #000;
    background-position: 10px 6px;
    float: left;
}
```

I tried to set the file's css to the inputlong css but there was nothing !

So how to create a similar css like this for a file element ?

Comment: Browsers implement stringent limits around file inputs, and behavior across browsers is inconsistent. See this answer I just wrote up for a few alternatives which may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546074/cross-browser-issue-need-advice/10546154#10546154

Answer (score 1):

For security reason, you cannot do exactly what you want with a `file`.

Most solution I know of change the opacity of the "browse" button so the user see what is behind.

For example :

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

Answer (score 1):

A [`file` element](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html), like a `select`, `checkbox` or `radiobutton` element is a os/browser controlled html element. You can [style it with javascripts](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) but (almost) not with css